# Getting middleware errors in integrating django cms with existing django project

Tags: django, django-cms

I have a working django project which contains around ten apps. I am integrating django cms in my app, so I can edit the pages content. I have followed the procedure of the documentation but I am getting middleware errors when I am doing "python manage cms check". The errors are in this format:

```
 cms.middleware.user.CurrentUserMiddleware middleware must be in MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES [ERROR]
```

My middlewares are in following order in my settings.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
  'cms.middleware.utils.ApphookReloadMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
  'cms.middleware.user.CurrentUserMiddleware',
  'cms.middleware.page.CurrentPageMiddleware',
  'cms.middleware.toolbar.ToolbarMiddleware',
  'cms.middleware.language.LanguageCookieMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What version of django-cms are you using?

Comment: @neverwalkaloner 3.3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In django 1.10 old style middlware has been deprecated. Seems like new style [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#middleware) was added only in [django-cms 3.4.1](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/5688).
Try to update django-cms.